# How to prevent users from copying their outlook pst file to an external disk or system

Tags: data-leakage, exchange

We allow 4 gb space per employee in outlook mail exchange, beyond that the user has to create a pst file . That is the policy.

We have given admin rights to all employees since there is a lot of travelling and site visits. Before an employee leaves the company, he always copies the pst files into an external drive. This is leakage of valuable information.

Is there a way to prevent the pst files from being copied into an external drive/laptop?
And if the need arises, only the IT admin should be able to do it.

I am looking for some sort of encryption or exchange policy for this. Any solution is welcome. Thanks a million

Answer (score 3):

There is no reason to give your employee local admin rights on their computer, there is the principle of least privilege, please look it up and implement it. Giving everyone admin rights is a big no-no and can be even more dangerous when it comes to data leakage as successful attacks to your employee's their computer can now also result in exposure of your domain administrator account (due to cached credentials).

Furthermore data extraction is very hard to solve if the employee has rights to read the file in the first place. If you are allowed to read the file (which I imagine is important if you want to read email) then there is nothing you can do.

The only way to solve this is to set up a policy which explicitly disallows storing PST (or any other corporate data for  that matter) on non-company approved external media. When they leave the company they are required to return all media. If they don't do this after they leave the company and you can prove they actually took company secrets with them, you can sue them for corporate/industrial espionage.